# How do I make a top level query on belongsToMany association in Sequelize?

Tags: associations, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I need to get all Tags that belongs to a Post.

First, I managed Post and Tag via `belongsToMany` association as like as table `post_tag`. These models were built as below:

```
Post.belongsToMany(Tag, {
  as: 'tags',
  through: {
    model: PostTag,
    unique: true,
  },
  foreignKey: 'post_id',
  constraints: true
});

Tag.belongsToMany(Post, {
  as:'posts',
  through: {
    model: PostTag,
    unique: true,
  },
  foreignKey: 'tag_id',
  constraints: true
});
```

Then, I wrote a good working statment like this:

```
Post.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Tag, as: 'tags',
    attributes: ['id','name'],
    through: {attributes:[]}
  }]
})
//JSON result 
[
  { 
    "title": "Post title 1",
    "tags": [
      {"id":1, "name": "tagA"},
      {"id":2, "name": "tagB"}
    ]
  },
  { 
    "title": "Post title 2",
    "tags": [
      {"id":1, "name": "tagA"},
      {"id":3, "name": "tagC"}
    ]
  }
]
```

When I was trying to filter post by `tagA`, I still got 2 post same above. But `tagB` and `tagC` were lost in the nested propery `tags`:

```
    Post.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Tag, as: 'tags',
        attributes: ['id','name'],
        through: {attributes:[]},
        where: {name:'tagA'} // <--- Add filter here
      }]
    })
    //JSON result 
    [
      { 
        "title": "Post title 1",
        "tags": [
          {"id":1, "name": "tagA"}  // <-- tagB was gone
        ]
      },
      { 
        "title": "Post title 2",
        "tags": [
          {"id":1, "name": "tagA"}  // <-- tagC was gone
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I read [Sequelize document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models) which guides us move the `where` to top level, but it only works with `hasMany` association.

```
   Post.findAll({
      where: {'$tags.name$':'tagA'} // <--- move query to top here follow the guide
      include: [{
        model: Tag, as: 'tags',
        attributes: ['id','name'],
        through: {attributes:[]},            
      }]
    })
```

Is there any way to keep `tagB` and `tagC` in the result?

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7541

Comment: TAGS need an ID ! Everything will be resolve

Comment: Or "Instead use attributes: { exclude: ['id'] }, to exclude the id (if your MySQL table has no id column)"

Comment: I also attach the id column in attributes:["id", "name"] (as you see I've updated JSON RESULT) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Post.findAll where "TagA" return id post and then each loop > get full infomation include tags inside !

Comment: I prefer to use Eager Loading rather than using Lazy Loading cause of the query's time. I will give it a shot if no solution comes.